# Exclude Expired Announcements from search results SP 2013

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have an announcement list where I am using Expires field. I want to filter out these expired items from search. I tried to modify the search query of search results web part using expression `-Expires<{Today}` it shows no results. But when I tried greater than sign still it doesn't show results. I think I am missing something over here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is a managed named `Expires` and that it is mapped to Date based crawled property and not the text based crawled property in Search service application. See this for more information:
[Filtering by Start Date and End Date in a Content Search Web Part](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2013/06/28/filtering-by-start-date-and-end-date-in-a-content-search-web-part.aspx)